# Remove UIEditMenuInteraction from PKCanvasView

Tags: ios, swift, pencilkit

I have been working with PencilKit for quite some time now and never had any problems with it.
However, since updating to iOS17 my app shows a menu when the PKCanvasView is tapped.

[image]

As I implement my own menu I want to remove this, but unfortunately I do not have any idea how to do this.

Comment: can you please share some snippet too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the thing that worked for me

```
extension PKCanvasView {
    func disableMenuInteractions() {
        let views = [self] + self.allSubviewsRecursive()
        for view in views {
            for interaction in view.interactions where interaction is UIEditMenuInteraction {
                view.removeInteraction(interaction)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works! But now I get these errors/warnings in the console when tapping on PKCanvasView: "The edit menu (configuration: (null)) can only be presented when the view is in a window scene: (null)". Should I be concerned? pic: https://i.imgur.com/dljCLCu.png